# Uncomment a line based on occurrence of a pattern in another line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
File1:

json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

I want to uncomment the line starting with DELETE if there is pattern optype anywhere above.

Desired output:

```
json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

If the file doesn't have the pattern optype above then no modifications are needed.

```
File2:

json ABC
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

Desired output:

```
json ABC
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE     
json IJK
```

How to accomplish this via `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: Once a comment is gone, how should the following comments be handled? Should each have an optype above it or is it enough to have just one in the entire file before all the comments?

Comment: The data mention the word `json`. Is there any actual JSON contents in your data? If so, this would possibly be trivial, or at least easier, to solve with a JSON-aware tool.

Comment: Your example would have been more useful for testing with if it also had a `--DELETE `line above the `optype` line to test that that line did not get modified.

Answer (score 6):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/optype/,$ s/^--\(DELETE\)/\1/'
```

Which runs the `s`ubstitute command on all lines from the first one matching the `optype` regexp (that is which contains `optype`) to the last line (`$`).

Note that if there's a line like `--DELETE optype` it will both be considered as the start of the range and be uncommented.

The `perl` equivalent:

```
perl -pe 's/^--(?=DELETE)// if /optype/..0'
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '/optype/, 0 {sub("^--DELETE", "DELETE")}; {print}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to manipulate every `--DELETE...` after the occurrence of `optype ?`, you can use this GNU `sed`;

```
$ sed -E '/^optype/{:a;n;s/^--(DELETE)/\1/;ba}' input_file
```

This will edit every occurrence of `--DELETE...` after any line starting with `ostype ?`, if this is not the intended behaviour and you'd like to edit only the first occurrence after `ostype ?`, then you can use this GNU `sed` instead

```
$ sed -E '/^optype/{:a;t;n;s/^--(DELETE)/\1/;ba}' input_file
json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

This will remove the comment from one `--DELETE` after every occurrence of `ostype ?` no matter the amount of comments that occur after each `ostype

Answer (score 3):

A perl approach:

```
perl -pe '$k++ if /optype/; s/^--(?=DELETE)// if $k' file2
```

We increment a variable's value if a line matches `optype` and then delete the `--` from any line starting with `--DELETE` if the variable is set. The `?=` construct is a [positive lookahead](https://regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php).

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'f && /^--DELETE/{sub(/--/,"")} /optype/{f=1} 1' file
json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
DELETE OP_TYPE
json IJK
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

First **with** optype:

```
$ cat File1 
json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
$ awk 'BEGIN{unco=0}{if($0~/optype/){unco=1};if(unco){gsub(/^--/,"")}; print }' File1 
json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

Then without:

```
$ cat File1 
json ABC
ptype D
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
$ awk 'BEGIN{unco=0}{if($0~/optype/){unco=1};if(unco){gsub(/^--/,"")}; print }' File1 
json ABC
ptype D
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

We set a flag, `unco`, if a line contains `optype`.

If the flag is set we trim off `--` of any subsequent line.

And we print every line.

If you use `GNU awk` you can utilise the inline function to modify the file in place; otherwise redirect to a tmp-file and `mv` that over the original.

Comment: This will also remove the `--` from lines that don't contain `DELETE` though.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '/optype/,/,/{if($0 ~ /^--DELETE/){gsub("--DELETE","DELETE",$0)}}1' filename
```

output

```
json ABC
optype D
json XYZ
json IJK
DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

```
awk '/optype/,/,/{if($0 ~ /^--DELETE/){gsub("--DELETE","DELETE",$0)}}1' file2.txt
```

output

```
json ABC
json XYZ
json IJK
--DELETE OP_TYPE 
json IJK
```

Comment: Rhetorical questions: Why search for `/,/`? Why use `$0 ~` (the default)? Why test for `/^--DELETE/` before calling `gsub()` which tests for it again? Why add `,$0` (the default) to the end of `gsub()`? etc.